# Tangent vector to a curve.

Tags: curves

Given the curve
$$r(t)=(t,t^2,2)$$
I have to find the tangent vector to $r$ at $Q(1,1,2)$. From the coordinates of $Q$, I know that $t=1$, so the tangent vector is
$$r'(1)=(1,2,0)$$
But when I plot the curve $r$ and the vector $r'(1)-r(1)=(0,1,-2)$ in Geogebra it's not tangent at all. What's wrong?

Comment: $(1, 1, 2) + (1, 2, 0) s$ will be tangent to $r(t)$.

Comment: @MathLover what is $s$?

Comment: a scalar, just like $t$

Comment: @MathLover So a tangent vector could be $(0,-1,2)$?

Comment: Tangent vector at point $(1, 1, 2)$ is $(1, 2, 0)$

Comment: But tangent vector is just a direction. We need to also specify one of the points on the line in addition to tangent vector to uniquely identify the tangent line.

Comment: @MathLover I need to find the directional derivative of a function in the direction of the tangent vector to $r$ at $Q$.So I thought to take $(1,2,0)$.

Comment: please find the gradient of the function and do dot product with unit vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(1, 2, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you must plot the vector $(1,2,0)$ starting at $Q(1,1,2)$ (you have possibly drawn it starting from $(0,0,0)$). A sketch is as follows
[image]